# KeystoneJS can't update post

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, keystonejs

> **UPDATE** It seems the problem is I can't update/edit my post. Every time I create a new post, then it enter **dead loop**. Please help me T-T

Recently I started a program using keystoneJS as my CMS.
Everything goes fine but this Post problem.
I have found if I install keystone-demo via `yo keystone`(using the KeystoneJS generator made with Yeoman) then publishing post can work, but if I install keystone manually, the problem comes...
In Google Inspect Console, there is a error-
`"TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'refList.expandColumns')"`

I guess it is the keystone version problem.
This is my `package.json` file

```
{
  "name": "keystone-demo",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/JedWatson/keystone-demo.git"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "keystone": "https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone.git",
    "async": "^1.5.0",
    "lodash": "^3.10.1",
    "csv": "^0.4.6",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-less": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-shell": "^0.5.2",
    "gulp-watch": "^4.3.5",
    "pug": "^2.0.0-alpha6"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node keystone.js"
  }
}
```

And this is the `package.json` file in that can work normally version

```
{
  "name": "keystone",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "keystone": "^0.3.16",
    "async": "^1.5.0",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3",
    "node-sass": "^3.3.2",
    "node-sass-middleware": "^0.9.7", 
    "dotenv": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.7.0",
    "gulp-jshint": "^1.9.0",
    "jshint-stylish": "^0.1.3",
    "gulp-shell": "^0.5.0",
    "gulp-watch": "^4.3.5",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.0.4"

  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.22",
    "npm": ">=1.3.14"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node keystone.js"
  },
  "main": "keystone.js"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're loading the latest keystone version from github, which is not always stable. This is probably the reason for the error you're seeing.

I recommend using the latest version published to npm (0.3.22 at time of writing) instead.

Update the first line in your dependencies to this, and it will work:

```
"keystone": "^0.3.22",
```

To add keystone to a new project you can also type `npm install --save keystone`